# Relation agreggate selecting highest value and lowest value

Tags: qgis

Two tables linked with 1 to n relationship

I would like to do a relation_aggregate so that I would get the highest value (real) from a field in the child table.

And the same expression but for the lowest value.

Comment: If your Question can't answer the questions "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" it is likely to collect closure votes. You also seem running up against the One question per Question policy.

Answer (score 1):

found it. Thanks anyway!

for max

```
relation_aggregate('relation','max', "field(real)")
```

for min

```
relation_aggregate('relation','min', "field(real)")
```